# Half pyramid number column multiples

Tags: python

Need help creating a 9 column descending half pyramid.
The first column must count 1-9.
Then with each row they should continue counting with that starting multiple. Would appreciate any help please.

```
for num in range(10):
    for i in range(num):
        print (num, end=" ")
    print("\n")

>Current output

1

2 2

3 3 3

4 4 4 4

5 5 5 5 5

6 6 6 6 6 6

7 7 7 7 7 7 7

8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

>I need it to output as:

1

2 4

3 6 9

4 8 12 16

5 10 15 20 25

6 12 18 24 30 36

7 14 21 28 27 35 42

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Comment: Do you see any common ground between the rows? 2ed row has 2 gap between the numbers, 3rd row has 3 gap between the numbers...

Comment: Btw, you should revise your multiplication table of 6. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your inner looping wrong. Considering the outer loop represents line numbers, the inner loop should start from line number, incrementing each time by line number till the square of line number:

```
for num in range(1, 10):
    for i in range(num, num*num+1, num):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print("\n")

# 1
# 2 4
# 3 6 9
# 4 8 12 16
# 5 10 15 20 25
# 6 12 18 24 30 36
# 7 14 21 28 35 42 49
# 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
# 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there! just a few minor adjustments:

```
for mul in range(1, 10):
    for i in range(1, mul+1):
        print (i * mul, end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

what you need to print is `i * mul`; and the `range` needs to start at `1` and stop at (i.e. one before) `mul+1`.

a bit more compact and neatly aligned:

```
for mul in range(1, 10):
    print(' '.join(f'{mul*i:2d}' for i in range(1, mul+1)))
```

this outputs:

```
 1
 2  4
 3  6  9
 4  8 12 16
 ...
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Comment: I would like to compare these two answer codes. Just asking, isn't doing multiplication in the loop context (as in my code) than within the loop everytime more efficient?

Comment: @Austin i agree! (+1) tried to be close to the original primarily to point out the things that do not work...